# Display text based on SESSION in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following line of code that displays a user's first name once logged in.  I had text that says Welcome, before the echo statement but it looks silly unless you are logged in.  Is there a quick way to only display Welcome, if the session FirstName is not empty?

```
<h2><?php echo "".$_SESSION['FirstName'];?></h2>
```

I'd like to use PHP isset but I still don't know how to hide Welcome, and display only if the session contains data.

Comment: Yes.  Use an `if` statement, since no code is provided, I can't help much more.

Comment: Have you header of conditionals (i.e. `if()`)?

Comment: Yes, but what is the proper syntax to check for $_SESSION FirstName?

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco `isset($_SESSION['FirstName'])`

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['FirstName'])`

Comment: The syntax was the problem, this worked:  <h2><strong><?php echo ( isset($_SESSION['FirstName'])?"Welcome, ".$_SESSION['FirstName']."":"");?></strong></h2>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to check the variable or array value exist or not, you can use isset. For ypur case, you can do as follow.

```
<h2><?php echo ( isset($_SESSION['FirstName'])?"Welcome":"");?></h2>
```

Comment: Where would you put the Welcome, text?

Comment: Cool...I only want Welcome to show if session is present...that prints it regardless?

Comment: `<h2><?php echo (isset($_SESSION['FirstName'])?$_SESSION['FirstName']:" Welcome Guest!");?></h2>`

Comment: Updated my answer for your question

Comment: Got it...thanks, here is what I ended up with based on your answer:  <h2><strong><?php echo ( isset($_SESSION['FirstName'])?"Welcome, ".$_SESSION['FirstName']."":"");?></strong></h2>